# Widget runs only when selected in Simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I created a widget for my app. If I run the app and then add the widget in the simulator it does not work how it should work.

But If I click on my widget and then run it everything works fine.
I added a picture for more understanding.

What can I do?
[image: Xcode Simulator]

Comment: What is your Xcode version and on which version is your simulator running?

Comment: My Xcode Version is Version 12.0.1 (12A7300) and Simulator Version 12.0.1 (940.16)